# Improving pocketsphinx accuracy and reliability

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using *pocketsphinx* on ROS Hydro to implement speech recognition in my project.
Unfortunately, its accuracy is not so good for a few specific words, and this affects system reliability.

Therefore, in order to find a way to improve its efficiency, I've got a few questions:

1. Is it possible to "train" it? (e.g. I keep saying the words and stating if *pocketpshinx* understood them right or not, so it gets better with time).
2. No matter what I say, it always finds the most similar word defined in the **.dic** file. Is it possible to define a *threshold* so it'll only output a word if the similarity between the spoken word and the one defined in the file is above this threshold?
3. Is it ok to manually edit the **.dic** file in order to include different ways a word can be spoken? Do I need to change anything in the **.lm** file?

P.S: The speech recognition works really well for almost all the word I defined, but it's really unstable to some specifc ones. For example, the words **toilet** and **lift** are usually recognised as the words **to the** or **go to**, even though they're very different.

Does anyone have any recommendation of how to improve the accuracy?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189461/improving-pocketsphinx-accuracy-and-reliability/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can adapt the acoustic model of pocketsphinx. But it's not that easy as you described it (even the Sphinx wiki says it's not easy)

Have a look [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt).

Your other questions I can't answer. I haven't work much with pocketsphix, because it doesn't meet our requirements.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-08-08**:
I'll take a look in the link. Thanks!